# How to use "Object?.property" syntax in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I can use this way to prevent undefined error when  the object is undefined  , but it not work in React. i want to know is this ES6’syntax  or other syntax?

Comment: Why is it related to Angular?

Comment: sorry ;  forgot to say that:  i can use this syntax in angular2 project.but doesn't work in react project

Comment: *"EC6’syntax or other syntax?"* Not it's not. Seems to be some custom syntax from angular.

Answer (score 4):

The [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator) is a feature of Angular, and not part of the JavaScript langauge. As a result, it will not work in React applications.

Comment: Usually people use _.get from lodash.

Comment: but lodsh not work too..i don't know why every time i got undefiend

such as _.get({name:"123"},'name')  and returned undefined